# Kenwood TS 520 S Meter accidentally run without an antenna connected

Tags: transceiver, kenwood, equipment-troubleshooting

I powered up my Kenwood TS 520 without connecting the antenna and after 1 hour realized it was not connected, after connecting the antenna I noticed the S-meter was not giving me a reading and I have no idea why

Comment: As can be found on  Electronics.SE, powering radio equipment without an antenna connected can kill TX/RX electronics: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/335916/47092 I think it's likely that you accidentally killed the device by not having an antenna connected.

Comment: Do you have any more details to share? I'm not sure we can diagnose the issue without some more information.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you tried to transmit without an antenna, it should be fine.

If the radio is in receive mode without an antenna, it won't hurt it.  But if you transmit without an antenna, especially at high power, the high SWR could damage the final amplifier in the radio.